# WPF Using SurfaceListBox - highlight color selection

Tags: wpf, listbox, transparent

I need help to change the color of SurfaceListBox selection.

For now Im using this:

```
<Style x:Key="styleSurfaceListBox" TargetType="{x:Type my:SurfaceListBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
       <Setter.Value>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Background="Transparent" />                        
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>            
</Style>
```

What I need to make the selection color transparente?

Comment: You can find answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794792/wpf-listbox-selection-color)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dvvrd!

I create my `SurfaceListBoxItem` style like this:

```
     <Style x:Key="item" TargetType="{x:Type my:SurfaceListBoxItem}"  >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            </Trigger>                
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Then I point it to `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
SurfaceListBox1.ItemContainerStyle = (Style)this.Resources["item"]; //item is the KEY on my style.
```

Thanks again to dvvrd!