# Keeping custom style of ListBoxItem when selected

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ListBox where the background color of the items are bound to some property of the entry:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollectionOfFoos}" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle >
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding SomePropertyOfFoo}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnotherPropertyOfFoo}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

This works, but when I mouse over or select an item the background changes (unsurprisingly perhaps) to the default mouse over / selected color.

I'm new to WPF and I'm not sure I'm going about doing this kind of thing correctly, I thought maybe I need to use `ItemContainerStyleSelector`, but I'm confused as to how to use it, and it seems silly to have to create a class just for this small thing...

What I also thought was to create an IValueConverter from boolean to the color, and then bind though it without having to use DataTrigger as a different approach, would that be more elegant? would that some how help me with this problem?

**Edit**

It would also be nice if I could change the background color of the selected item to a different color based on `AnotherPropertyOfFoo`, if it's not too much to ask

**edit 2 (extension to comment on @Sheridan answer):**

this does not work

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem>one</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>two</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>three</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>four</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox.Items>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also override Template of ListBoxItem, extract default using blend and override or use [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794792/wpf-listbox-selection-color) already mentioned here.

**Edit**

Actually it is not so hard to override Template :) and I guess it is most correct way to solve your problem. Try this ItemContainer style. It replaces default ListBoxItem style->Template. To see how does it work - in triggers you can change any property of listbox item.

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The default style of ListBoxItem you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to make required modifications.

Comment: I'm not using blend, and to be honest, I'd rather avoid this solution as it seem to be like killing a fly with a tactical nuke... there has to be a simple strait forward way of doing this, hasn't there?

Comment: Grab the Style from edited post and try to experiment. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, But I still want to bind the color to a Boolean property, do I have to use a IValueConverter?

Comment: Use yours DataTrigger inside ControlTemplate.Triggers

Comment: I appreciate your help, but considering that now my options are to have my ListBox look different from the look of the rest of the application, or to past in 61 lines of mostly redundant XAML for a simple UI feature, I hope you'll forgive me for not excepting your answer... My frustration is not with you, but with WPF, but I'm still hoping against hope for a better answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollectionOfFoos}" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle >
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding SomePropertyOfFoo}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnotherPropertyOfFoo}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

The `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` represents the default background colour of the selected item in collection controls... here it is set to `Transparent`, but you can set it to which ever colour you prefer.

UPDATE >>>

This code works just fine... if you change the first `SolidColorBrush` in the `Resources` section to `Red`, then the selected item background colour will be `Red`. Your `Binding` of `AnotherPropertyOfFoo` will not affect the selected item as there is no relationship between the two. To achieve that, you can try this instead:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableCollectionOfFoos}" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle >
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" >
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding SomePropertyOfFoo}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding AnotherPropertyOfFoo}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Now the selected item will get the background colour from the `AnotherPropertyOfFoo` property.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but this simply does not have any effect. I've Isolated it in the simplest example i could create and it still does not work, see the edit to my post for the code I used, maybe you can find my mistake