# change selection animation in wpf listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, listbox, selection

I have to change animation in WPF listbox, because I use my own.

[image]

The light blue is my selection (I made it with event select_changed and then I changed TextBlock.Background into lightblue)

The blue selection is the default, which I want to be transparent so that the selection will be more elegant.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
        foreach (var item in myListBox.Items)
            (item as TextBlock).Background = Brushes.White;
        if (myListBox.SelectedItem != null)
            (myListBox.SelectedItem as TextBlock).Background= Brushes.LightBlue;
        myListBox.ScrollIntoView(myListBox.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: Implement your own ItemContainerStyle for a Listbox, hope this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466521/keeping-coustum-style-of-listboxitem-when-selected/18467790#18467790

Comment: Yes, thanks o lot.
its the thing want i want to :)
now its beautiful listbox

Answer (score 1):

Just add this `Style` to your `ListBox`:

```
<Style x:Key="HiddenDefaultSelectionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

You can replace the `colour` `Transparent` with whichever colour you prefer. I believe that the names of these properties are self explanatory.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for you to add that `Style` to your `ListBox`.